# System Settings > System Upgrade link does not exists

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2, setup-upgrade, magento-upgrade

I am trying to update to the latest version of Magento from 2.2 and want to do it from the admin panel. However the System Upgrade link under system doesn't exist. Did I mess something up with my install? I have only one account with this system and it is admin. I am using the install to run m2e so everything is basic settings.

[image: magento 2 no system settings link]

Answer (score 0):

Check the prerequisities list:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman.html

---

```
/**
     * Removes 'Web Setup Wizard' from the menu if doc root is pub and no setup url variable is specified.
     *
     * @param Builder $subject
     * @param Menu $menu
     * @return Menu
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetResult(Builder $subject, Menu $menu)
    {
        if ($this->docRootLocator->isPub()) {
            $menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');
        }
        return $menu;
    }
```

You may also check if doc root is pub and setup url is available

Comment: I am not seeing any issues. Cron has been running for weeks, no file system permission issues that I can see.